# solr 9.3.0 add-repo returns mime-type error

Tags: dataimporthandler, solr-9.3.0

I've installed SOLR 9.3.0 in a windows 10 environment. The command line interface is functional and the solr dashboard displays.

I'm trying to add the now separate data import handler package per the instructions here: https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler

I've started solr in cloud mode with package support enabled, but the add-repo command returns the error: Error from server at [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/searchscale/dataimporthandler/master/repo/repository.json?wt=json&version=2.2"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/searchscale/dataimporthandler/master/repo/repository.json?wt=json&version=2.2%22) followed by what looks like the json for the package output in the window where the command was entered.

I've reproduced the error in an ubuntu 22.04 environment with the same results.

Is there a way to specify that the solr package commands use json? Or what am I missing?